# How can I split a list with embedded transition markers using LINQ or Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, system.reactive

I have the following input, arriving from an external source:

```
IEnumerable<string> = new [] { "1", "5", "Transition Good->Bad", "3", "2",    
                              "Transition Bad->Good", "7", "Transition Good->Bad", 
                              "9", "12" };
```

And I'd like to extract a list that contains only "Good" values, so in this case, that would be 1,5,7.  I cannot make any assumptions about how many transitions there will be, and whether the first transition will be from "Good" to "Bad" or the other way around.

My current solution is use `Enumerable.First` to find the first transition (to check whether the first values are Good or Bad), and then do a foreach loop over the input, maintaining a "isValueGood" boolean throughout.

Is there a more eloquent approach of doing this, using LINQ or Reactive Extensions?

**EDITED**: Expanded question to ask for possible solutions in Rx as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ really shines when working element by element, so I would suspect any approach using LINQ is not really going to be elegant (because whether or not to stream a particular value depends on values farther along in the sequence).

I would do what you're doing, but slightly different. Rather than using `Enumerable.First`, I would store the current state as a value of

```
enum State { Good, Bad, Unknown };
```

Set the initial state to Unknown. Buffer the values until you know the state. If the state indicates that the first set of values was in a `Good` state, output those buffered values, and then proceed as you describe. The prevents a possibly `O(n)` walk to find the initial state, and it prevents walking the sequence twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static IEnumerable<string> GetGoodItems(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        var first = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i == "bad->good" || i == "good->bad");
        return first != null
            ? first == "bad->good"
                ? GetGoodItemsImpl(items.SkipWhile(i => i != "bad->good").Skip(1)) 
                : GetGoodItemsImpl(items) 
            : GetGoodItemsImpl(items);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetGoodItemsImpl(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        var goodItems = items.TakeWhile(i => i != "good->bad");
        var remaining = items.SkipWhile(i => i != "bad->good").Skip(1);
        return remaining.Any() ? goodItems.Concat(GetGoodItems(remaining)) : goodItems;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var values = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "good->bad", "13", "14", "15", "bad->good", "2", "1", "good->bad", "15", "12", "11", "bad->good", "3" };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetGoodItems(values)));

        var values2 = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "bad->good", "13", "14", "15", "good->bad", "2", "1", "bad->good", "15", "12", "11", "good->bad", "3" };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetGoodItems(values2)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `seq` defined as in your post, a linq one-liner would be:

```
bool? good=null, first=null;
var result=seq
  .Select(w=>new 
  { 
    g=(w.Contains("Good->")?(good=(first.HasValue?false:!(first=true)))
      :(w.Contains("Bad->")?(good=(first.HasValue?true:!(first=false))):good)), 
    n=w.Contains("->")?null:w
  })
  .Where(w=>w.n!=null && ((!good.HasValue)||(good.HasValue&&good.Value))).ToArray()
  .Where(w=>(w.g.HasValue&&w.g.Value)||(!w.g.HasValue&&first.Value))
  .Select(w=>w.n);
```

I had to force the `ToArray()` to restart the parsing of the sequence, otherwise it's linear. The `g` in the first sequence is to let me do calculations at each step while still selecting everything.

I can almost feel Eric Lippert shuddering at my post... again.

Comment: +1 for effort, but it makes my eyes bleed - Linq is not the right tool for solving this problem

Comment: This is disgusting, and just underscores my point that LINQ is not the right approach here.

Comment: It isn't a good use of LINQ anyway if it depends on mutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do this in Rx:

```
var allGoodStates = Observable.Concat(
    states.TakeUntil(x => stateTransitionsToBad(x)).Where(x => isNotTransition()),
    states.TakeUntil(x => stateTransitionsToGood(x).Where(_ => false)
).Repeat();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you expand a bit on how this works? I don't quite understand. Also, I assume stateTransitionsToBad, stateTransitionsToGood, and isNotTransition methods don't do anything but check if the string is equal to one of the constants? Also, will it work no matter what type of transition is the first one?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit of the problem, are you saying that when the stream starts, you have no idea whether the values are valid or not?

Comment: @Omer Yeah, the three fn's are just simple string compares, I just left them out to make the code more readable

Comment: @Paul Yes, that is part of the problem. Is there some way to fix the above code to handle that? It looks very promising

Comment: @Omer Hmmm, it definitely makes the problem more complicated... I'll have to think about it

Comment: @Paul - I think you mean `TakeWhile` - `TakeUntil` is the `IObservable` one

Answer (score 1):

Here are few choices, pick one. Let's name our enumerable e:

```
        var e = new[]
                     {
                         "1", "5",
                         "Transition Good->Bad",
                         "3", "2",
                         "Transition Bad->Good",
                         "7",
                         "Transition Good->Bad",
                         "9", "12"
                     };
```

If you have enumerable and the on/off signal is mixed in, then using .Scan() is most evident. It is basically a functional version of a foreach loop with a mutable flag:

```
        var goods = e
            .Scan(Tuple.Create("", 1),
                  (x, y) => Tuple.Create(y,
                      y.StartsWith("Transition") 
                      ? y.EndsWith("Good") ? 1 : -1 
                      : x.Item2))
            .Where(x => !x.Item1.StartsWith("Transition") && x.Item2 > 0)
            .Select(x => x.Item1);
```

If you have enumerable and don't mind writing your own extension function specifically for this case, using yield return is probably most elegant:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SplitByMarkers<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> fMarker)
    {
        var isOn = true;
        foreach (var value in source)
        {
            var m = fMarker(value);
            if (m == 0)
                if (isOn)
                    yield return value;
                else
                    continue;
            else
                isOn = m > 0;
        }
    }
        var goods = e.SplitByMarkers(x => 
            x.StartsWith("Transition") 
            ? x.EndsWith("Good") ? 1 : -1 
            : 0);
```

If you have observable, and especially if the markers exist as a separate observable, the best option to create AndOn extension based on .CombineLatest:

```
    public static IObservable<TSource> AndOn<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source, IObservable<bool> onOff)
    {
        return source
            .CombineLatest(onOff, (v, on) => new { v, on })
            .Where(x => x.on)
            .Select(x => x.v);
    }
```

You can use AndOn with the above enumerable like this:

```
        var o = e.ToObservable().Publish();
        var onOff = o
            .Where(x => x.StartsWith("Transition"))
            .Select(x => x.EndsWith("Good"))
            .StartWith(true);
        var goods = o
            .AndOn(onOff)
            .Where(x => !x.StartsWith("Transition"));

        using (goods.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
        using (o.Connect())
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

And finally, RX geek way, using the Join operator available in the Dec 2010 drop of RX:

```
        var o = e.ToObservable().Publish();
        var gb = o.Where(x => x == "Transition Good->Bad");
        var bg = o.Where(x => x == "Transition Bad->Good").Publish("");
        var goods =
            from s in o
            join g in bg on Observable.Empty<string>() equals gb
            where !s.StartsWith("Transition")
            select s;

        using (goods.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
        using (bg.Connect())
        using (o.Connect())
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think methods such as GoodValues and BadValues make good sense, but I wouldn't implement them as extension methods to `IEnumerable<string>` types because they don't make sense for all `IEnumerable<string>` types. So I would make a quick little class (maybe called GoodBadList) that inherits from `IEnumerable<string>` and offers the two methods I mentioned. Those methods would, for each value in the list, look both forward and backward until a transition is found, determine which direction the transition is in and use that to either return or reject that value in the resulting list. 
I know it's fun to write elegant LINQ statements, but it's more fun to have an entire elegant solution which includes writing a class when it makes sense. This GoodBadList is a concept that seems to exist in your domain, so I would put it in bits. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your IEnumrable<string> is called input, you could do something like this:

```
bool addItem = input.First(item => item.StartsWith("Transition")).EndsWith("->Bad");
var good = input.Where(item =>
{
     if (item.StartsWith("Transition"))
     {
         addItem = item.EndsWith("->Good");
         return false;
     }
     return addItem;
 });
```

NOTE: This is similar to the way you are currently doing it with your foreach method.

Comment: this will fail quite spectacularly if someone else messes with the addItem variable before, or during, when the enumerator is accessed.

Comment: Thats like saying for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) will fail if someone messes with i. You are correct but... thats kind of obvious.

Comment: Sure, but mutating hoisted state leaves a very bad taste in my mouth. The result of enumerating a value returned from LINQ should not be different based off of the surrounding state.